# Зебрёнок, жирафёнок: есть ли такие слова?

Tags: словообразование

Есть ли в русском языке слова *зебрёнок*, *жирафёнок*? Если нет, то как назвать детёныша зебры, жирафа, бегемота?

Comment: А у многих животных такие названия есть. Вопрос о конкретных случаях.

Comment: А если есть, то зебреныш, жирафенок, бегемотёныш. )))

Answer (score 2):

"Русский язык" довольно непределенное множество... 
Если вы эти слова знаете и понимаете, значит они уже есть в каком-то смысле. 
Другое дело, что этих слов нет в нормативных словарях...
Но в данном случае могуу порадовать. "Зебрёнок" встречается довольно часто, претендуя на некоторую нормативность.

> Если нет, как назвать детеныша зебры, жирафа, бегемота?

Бегемотик.

Comment: А вот "Грамота.Ру" отвечает почему-то, что слова "зебренок" нет, а есть "зубрёнок"

Comment: Ну не совсеми так. Она отвечает, что зубрёнок есть в словарях, а зебрёнка там нет. В этом она права, нормативность "зуьренка" пока сомнительна. Но "зебренок" достаточно популярен, можно просто погуглить.

Answer (score 0):

Как у Незнайки: если придумал слова, значит, оно есть! Жирафёнок, бегемотёнок, зебрёнок и т. д. Главное, чтобы тебя поняли, о чём лопочешь!